# Trouble accessing an object's private function

Tags: c++, function, header-files, private, member

I have an assignment in which I cannot edit two header files, car.h and compass.h. In the file, car.h, there is a private function called:
`void load_car();`. This is later defined in car.cpp as:

```
void car::load_car(){
cout << "Please enter make and model:" << endl;
ifstream inFile;
string fileName;
fileName = (make + "-" + model + ".txt");
inFile.open(fileName.c_str());
//not a finished function
}
```

My problem is that I have a main function,

```
int main() {
cin >> make >> model;
car a(make, model);
a.load_car();

return 0;
}
```

where I can not call the object's private member function. How can I do this correctly without altering the car.h header. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

The error received when compiling with g++ is:

```
In file included from car.cpp:2:0:
car.h: In function ‘int main()’:
car.h:22:7: error: ‘void car::load_car()’ is private
  void load_car();
       ^
car.cpp:14:13: error: within this context
    a.load_car();
               ^
```

The full code is included below:
car.cpp

```
#include "compass.h"
#include "car.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

string make, model;

int main() {
    cin >> make >> model;
    car a(make,model);
    a.load_car();


    return 0;
}

void car::load_car(){

    cout << "Please enter make and model:" << endl;
    ifstream inFile;
    string fileName;
    fileName = (make + "-" + model + ".txt");
    inFile.open(fileName.c_str());
}
```

car.h

```
#ifndef CAR_H
#define CAR_H

#include <string>
#include "compass.h"

//Relative direction
enum class rDir {left, right};

class car
{
private:
    std::string make, model;
    int topSpeed, horsepower, mass;
    double currentSpeed = 0;

//Defined by compass.h: an x/y coordinate struct and cardinal direction.
    coordinates position;
    compass direction;

//Helper functions
    void load_car();
    void update_position();
public:

//Constructor/Destructor
    car (std::string ma, std::string mo) : make (ma), model (mo) {load_car();}
    ~car() {};

//Getters
    std::string get_make() {return make;}
    std::string get_model() {return model;}
    coordinates get_position() {return position;}
    compass get_direction() {return direction;}
    double get_speed() {return currentSpeed;}

//Things cars do
    void accelerate();
    void brake();
    void coast();
    void steer (rDir turn);
};


#endif // CAR_H
```

Comment: Be warned that you are posting an assignment based question with fairly weak description of the problem that is fairly difficult to skim, with non indented code, without providing self contained runnable examples. I don't this is going to go well unless you modify your question. My best advice is to break your problem down into self contained tests capturing exactly the part that you don't understand or confuses you. Based on your description you yourself don't seem like you know what you are asking.

Comment: Is there any place in the car class's implementation (i.e inside car.cpp) where load_car() is called?  Usually when someone makes a method private like that, they do so because they specifically *don't want* anyone outside of that same class to call that method.  So this suggests that the author of car.h doesn't want you to call load_car() (except perhaps from the implementation of a car::something() method, if you are allowed to edit car.cpp)

Comment: Maybe you could use the `friend class` from the documentation: http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/inheritance/ but as @Dmitry pointed out, attempt first.

Comment: After your edit showing the code - the car constructor already calls load_car, so you don't need to.

Comment: Ok; this is all super weird. First of all, like the above comment says, the car constructor already calls if, so you don't need to. Why do you think you need to call `load_car`? Secondly, `load_car` is documented as a "helper function", it's clearly not for you to use anyways. You just use the `car` constructor. And as I was typing this all into an answer I ran into the big mystery: *Who* actually wrote `load_car`? Did you do that? Because that `cout` message in there is completely inexplicable given what that function is actually *doing* and its context in the constructor.

Comment: @TheDark You were right. I had overlooked the fact that the constructor had called the helper function load_car().

Comment: @JasonC Yes, the cout is out of place as I was trying to test the code before writing more of the function. I later realized that the problem I had was that I was trying to call the helper function since I overlooked that the constructor itself was calling the function already. Sorry for the inconvenience

Answer (score 2):

If you are not allowed to modify car.h, you won't be able to call `a.load_car()` from `main`.

If you are not allowed to modify `main`, you have a bad assignment.

If you are creating your own `main`, find a way to do your assignment without calling `a.load_car()`.

Answer (score 0):

As The Dark mentioned, the load_car() function is called via the constructor and thus was not supposed to be called in the main() function.